# how to insert multiple rows into sqllite3 database

Tags: python-3.x, database, list, sqlite, executemany

I am trying to select rows and fetch them from the DB table and then insert them into a list so I can insert all of the rows at once into the database, but I got an error.

def paid_or_returned_buyingchecks(self):

```
    date = datetime.now()
    now = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    self.tenlistchecks=[]

    self.con = sqlite3.connect('car dealership.db')
    self.cursorObj = self.con.cursor()

    self.dashboard_buying_checks_dates = self.cursorObj.execute("select id, paymentdate , paymentvalue, car ,sellername from cars_buying_checks where nexttendays=?",(now,))
    self.dashboard_buying_checks_dates_output = self.cursorObj.fetchall()
    self.tenlistchecks.append(self.dashboard_buying_checks_dates_output)
    print(self.tenlistchecks)
    
    self.dashboard_buying_checks_dates = self.cursorObj.executemany("insert into paid_buying_checks VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)",[self.tenlistchecks])

    self.con.commit()
```

but I got an error :
[[(120, '21-08-2022', '1112', 'Alfa Romeo', 'james'), (122, '21-08-2022', '465', 'Buick', 'daniel '), (123, '21-08-2022', '789', 'Buick', 'daniel ')]]
self.dashboard_buying_checks_dates = self.cursorObj.executemany(
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 5, and there are 1 supplied.

Comment: Print self.tenlistchecks before inserting.

Comment: @PChemGuy thank you for the answering, this is exactly what I've got when printing (self.tenlistchecks) : 
[[(120, '21-08-2022', '1112', 'Alfa Romeo', 'james'), (122, '21-08-2022', '465', 'Buick', 'daniel '), (123, '21-08-2022', '789', 'Buick', 'daniel ')]]

Answer (score 1):

`self.cursorObj.fetchall()` returns a list of tuples, which is what you need to feed to `executemany`, so

```py
self.cursorObj.executemany("insert into paid_buying_checks VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)",self.tenlistchecks)
```

not

```py
self.cursorObj.executemany("insert into paid_buying_checks VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)",[self.tenlistchecks])
```

Comment: I've tried this and I got: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 5, and there are 2 supplied. to clarify the situation I have 2 rows only in the table

Comment: Run this https://trinket.io/python3/6d00f7098e, then change the data to yours. If you still have issues, provide the link to your fiddle showing the issue.

Comment: @ PChemGuy I got the same error

Comment: Where is the link to your fiddle? If you want my help, do the same thing. I want a link on the same site with your code and and data showing the error.